# How do I use a specific SSH key with SublimeGIT?

Tags: sublimetext, ssh-keys

I am using SublimeGit and it is defaulting to the 'id_rsa' key, but there are certain repos I am working on that use a different key in my ~/.ssh/ directory. If I have 'foo_rsa', for example, I cannot find out how to have SublimeGit use a specific key when running the commands.

Comment: is it per host? if so theres ways to configure based on that

Comment: It’s per repo. GitHub wont let me reuse keys. I couldn’t find it in the docs. Where do I put host settings?

Comment: per host would be something off of github.com or gitlab.com etc.  that seems to be the real issue - ive used different keys in github no problem

Comment: I'm able to use different keys in github, but since github doesn't let you reuse keys, I am unable to figure out how SublimeGit allows me to select which key to use when using the git commands.